# cron scheduler in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, cron

I am trying to set cron for a command or controller action but it seemed to be not working for me. Please see below what I have tried

I have been trying to set up scheduler as per your instructions with no result.

When I try: 
`1. /usr/local/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan cron:run` it gives error

```
Could not open input file: /home/mysite/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan

2. /usr/local/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/protected/app/controllers/TestController.php
```

it gives error `Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found in`

```
3. /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/mysite/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan cron:run
```

Error-`Could not open input file:`

```
4. php /var/www/com/mysite.com/artisan cron:run
Status: 404 Not Found No input file specified.
```

6. /usr/local/bin/php home/opendesk/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan.php and in artisan.php I do like Artisan::add(new CronRunCommand);

   Error Fatal error: Class 'Artisan' not found
7. /usr/local/bin/php /home/opendesk/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan.php
   when in artisan.php I change it to $artisan->add(new CronRunCommand);

   Error Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object

   None of it seems to work. I have been read many SO and google posts but cant find a solution to this. hoping to get some help here

Answer (score 0):

At first. Task Scheduling not available in laravel 4, you need use newest version.

At second. What a path `/home/mysite/public_html/protected/app/start/artisan`? Can you show application folder structure?

However `artisan` its file in application root folder in default installation. For sample - my application placed in `\var\www\myaplication` then artisan placed in `\var\www\myaplication\artisan`. And i call this `php \var\www\myaplication\artisan` or better, change current dir to `cd \var\www\myaplication` and run `php artisan`.

At trith artisan cron can not prepare controller method. You need create a cron task in file `App\Console\Kernel`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

For more details read [documenation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) this very useful!